# How to set a breakpoint in code from referenced .dll?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I am trying to set a breakpoint on a method from library System.Web.Mvc:

```
Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.EditorFor
```

The symbols are loaded. But how can I set a breakpoint if I can't open source code? I've tried "Debug > New Breakpoing > Break at Function" with

```
Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.EditorFor
```

but no luck.

Comment: do you want to set the breakpoint in the code for the method itself, or the code that calls the method?

Comment: I want to set breakpoint in method itself.